# Tableview delete crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

UPDATE: ADJUST THE INTEGER BEFORE DELETING THE CELL!

Why does the following crash on swipe to delete? My tableview number of rows depends on a NSInteger; so I don't understand what the problem is here.
By adjusting this integer, haven't I adjusted the datasource?

```
#import "sendWithQuestionOptionsController.h"

 @interface sendWithQuestionOptionsController ()
@property NSInteger NUMBER_OPTIONS;
@end

@implementation sendWithQuestionOptionsController


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.NUMBER_OPTIONS=4;
SHOULD_SHOW_OPTIONS=YES;

//make the UISegmentedControl.

 }

#define MIMIMUM_NUMBER_OPTIONS 2 //be sure to change the UI in all the viewControllers to handle this as well if you end up changing anything.

 #define POST_HEIGHT 150

  #define OPTION_HEIGHT 50

  #define HEADER_SECTION_HEIGHT 20

 BOOL SHOULD_SHOW_OPTIONS;

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
return cell;
}

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;
}


   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
if (section==0) {
    return 1;
}
if (section==1 ) {
    if (SHOULD_SHOW_OPTIONS)    {
        return self.NUMBER_OPTIONS;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
return 0;
}

  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
if (section==0) {
    return 0;
}
return HEADER_SECTION_HEIGHT; //for the options header...
 }

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section==0) {
    return POST_HEIGHT;
}
return OPTION_HEIGHT;
}

  -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  {

if (section==0) {
        return @""; //no title for the first header (first header isn't shown)
    }
    if (section==1) {
        if (self.NUMBER_OPTIONS==2)  {
            return @"Options";
        } else{
            return @"Options (swipe to delete)"; //they can still swipe to delete more.
        }
    }
    return @"";
}

 //called when user selects segmented control.
 -(void)selectedOptionsInSegmentedControl    {
SHOULD_SHOW_OPTIONS=YES;
self.NUMBER_OPTIONS=4;
 }

 //called when user selects segmented control.
 -(void)selectedNoOptionsInSegmentedControl  {
SHOULD_SHOW_OPTIONS=NO;
 }

 -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
if (indexPath.section==0)   {
    return NO;
}
if (indexPath.section==1)   {
    if (indexPath.row>MIMIMUM_NUMBER_OPTIONS-1)   {
        return YES;
    }
}
return NO;
 }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    self.NUMBER_OPTIONS-=1;
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}
 }


@end
```

Comment: Since you solved your own problem so quickly, you should either delete the question or post an actual answer with the proper solution (instead of simply adding an "update" at the start of the question).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update the NSInteger "datasource" first by calling self.NUMBER_OPTIONS-=1; and then remove the row.